# Obtaining the correlator of harmonic oscillator

Tags: harmonic-oscillator, quantum-chromodynamics, lattice-model

The two point function for harmonic oscillator can be written as

$$\langle \langle x(t_1)x(t_2) \rangle \rangle =\frac{\int Dx(t) x(t_1)x(t_2) e^{-S(x)}}{\int Dx(t) e^{-S(x)}} \tag{21} \, .$$ 
In Peter Lepage's paper -Lattice QCD for novices- this equation is followed by
$$\langle \langle x(t_1)x(t_2)\rangle \rangle = \frac{\sum e^{-E_n T} \langle E_n|xe^{-(H-E_n)t}|E_n\rangle}{\sum e^{-E_n T}} \tag{23}$$
where $T=t_{final}-t_{initial}$ and $t=t_2-t_1$. I cannot get how come we end up with Eq(23) from Eq(21). I have asked this question to my collegues, I have researched online. I could not find even a clue of the answer. So I ask here, as a last resort.